# `iau.cls` will not compile with a basic document

Tags: pdftex, color, undefined

I know there are some posts about this but none of them could solve my problem, which I think comes from the cls fils I am using. A very basic example to reproduce the error is:

```
\documentclass{iau}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
blah blah blah ...
\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup 
                      \ifx \@unusedoptionlist \@empty \else \@latex@warning@...
l.2 \begin{document}
                    
?
```

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\set@color ...\@pdfcolorstack push{\current@color 
                                                  }\aftergroup \reset@color 
l.5 \end{document}
                  
?
```

The `iau.cls` file can be download in the file [IAU_Author-Latex-template-Macro-Cambridge-2022.zip](https://www.iau.org/static/scientific_meetings/authors/). Maybe someone would find the problem.

Comment: The error appears in TeX Live 23/22/21 but compiles correctly using TeX Live 2020. If you are using Overleaf then you can change the TeX Live version to 2020 and compile your document. If it is a local installation of TeX Live, could you do provide more information about your setup please

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do have Tex Live 2023. Using 2020 version seems to remove that error indeed.

Comment: Hopefully that helped but check that the old version of packages isn't subtly changing figures/tables etc, not sure why it is raising an error though, more then likely an update to a package/class/LaTeX kernal and the class hasn't been updated.

Comment: always show errors in a code block, you showed it in a quote which wraps the lines so it is not clear which command is undefined. However that is the 2nd, spurious message. As is usually the case it is the first error that matters, the class needs an update for `\document`.  I added both error messaages to your question

Answer (score 3):

The class redefines `\document` in a way incompatible with recent latex releases. I can't see any essential features in the redefinition so this simply restores the standard latex command, and runs without error.

```
\let\Xdocument\document
\documentclass{iau}
\let\document\Xdocument
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
blah blah blah ...
\end{document}
```